# Como extrair apenas 1 imagem do Json?

Tags: json, angularjs

Olá, preciso extrair apenas 1 imagem deste Json. Aqui é meu código do angular para puxar os registros da api via get.

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('carrosCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
       $http.get("http://www.folhacar.com.br/api/listAnuncios?revenda_id=528&cnpj=13733235000134").success(function(data) { 
        $scope.nomes = data;
      });
    });
```

O campo nesta api é "imagens":["imagem01","imagem02","imagem03"]

Comment: Isso na verdade é um array e não um JSON.

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais isso na verdade é um JSON com uma array dentro; Porque tem uma array ão impossibilita de ser um `Object`

Comment: @MoshMage Perfeito, realmente. Deu a entender que o elemento "json" que se referia era somente `"imagens":["imagem01","imagem02","imagem03"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eu diria que um simples `data[N]` (onde `N` é um numero) retirará a parte que precisa. Ou isso ou `data.imagens[N]`. Mas como não sei como o servidor está a responder a essa query (aka não vemos o codigo do backend) é um bocado "ao sabor do vento" que digo isto.

Podes mostrar-nos como o backend responde a essa resposta?

Comment: Perfeito MoshMage, era exatamente isso, testei aqui e deu certo. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar a primeira imagem é simples assim:

```
var img = $scope.nomes.imagens[0];
console.log(img);
```

Exemplo:
http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=b3d9a7b5bd1765a942eede975554c67c